# first return response then return notifications in a method from service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf

In my service I have one method.That method returns 2 tables. Instead I want to return one table first, then another table. How to implement this scenario?

Please help me.

**
DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[1];

return dt;

...code....

return dt2

**

Comment: Please include what have you tried so far

Comment: from web service method return 2 tables one by one. 1st return 1st table data then 2nd table data.

Comment: can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Class with the 2 datatables and return that object.

Ex:

```
public class ReturnObject()
{
     public Datatable Table1 {get;set;}
     public Datatable Table2 {get;set;}
}
```

in your webservice:

```
ReturnObject returnObject = new ReturnObject();
returnObject.Table1 = DataTable1;
// some code
returnObject.Table2 = DataTable2;

return returnObject;
```

You should rename the objects for your own use.

Comment: thanks for your replay. But my requirement is Table1 is response to user. and Table 2 is notifications to user. After reached response to user then notification in a single webservice method

Comment: It is stil unclear what you mean with Response and notification. Can you provide more code / design? What are you trying to achieve on the other side of the webservice...